# Wordpress ?xyz ending on images

Tags: wordpress, cdn

When placing images into my Wordpress site they look as following:

http://cdn2.codepigeon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/phones1-e1328746637333.png?9d7bd4

but
http://cdn2.codepigeon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/phones1-e1328746637333.png
is the same image!

why does wordpress ad the ?xyz
and who do I stop it from doing so?

This could cause problems with a cdn (at least I think that some do not accept this)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it is used to prevent image caching by browser by requesting different URI (those number after the `?` sign), though they're essentially the same file.

I think there is no problem with that, because anything after the `?` sign is usually treated as request parameter, and may be ignored by the webserver.